# Explode characters in column of strings into multiple columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, split

My Dataframe is like:

```
       col1
   0   AGCT
   1   AGCT
```

How to turn it like this:

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4
0   A     G    C    T
1   A     G    C    T
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
*list comprehension* - You'd be surprised at how fast this is.

```
pd.DataFrame([list(x) for x in df.col1])

   0  1  2  3
0  A  G  C  T
1  A  G  C  T
```

---

**Option 2**
`pd.Series.apply` (less performant)

```
pd.DataFrame(df.col1.apply(list).tolist())

   0  1  2  3
0  A  G  C  T
1  A  G  C  T
```

---

**Option 3**
`pd.Series.extractall` + `unstack` (least performant)

```
df.col1.str.extractall('(.)')[0].unstack()

match  0  1  2  3
0      A  G  C  T
1      A  G  C  T
```

Comment: Can you explain what `.apply(list)` does? `list` here is a function?

Comment: @Spencer it applies a given function rowwise/columnwise for a dataframe. In this case, I called apply rowwise.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
df=df.col1.apply(list).apply(pd.Series)
df
Out[645]: 
   0  1  2  3
0  A  G  C  T
1  A  G  C  T
```

If performance is matter :-)

```
pd.DataFrame(list(map(list,df.col1.values)))
Out[647]: 
   0  1  2  3
0  A  G  C  T
1  A  G  C  T
```